# How could written materials be preserved after 3000 years of history?

Tags: science-based, history, written-material, preservation

**Premise**

Grandmaster Fredrietch Kalven, a researcher of lost arts, was tasked by the king to find and record all written histories of their world since the earliest writings.

After many years of research and studies, Fredrietch compiled the written works he collected from ancient libraries, buried ruins, heirlooms from noble houses, and oral passages from tribal natives. The Chronicles of History was later finished after the Grandmaster's death.

**Question**

How did these written materials such as scrolls, codices, and tomes survive
after 3000 years after wars and calamities, especially in those ancient libraries and ruins?

**Note**

Magic exist in this world and only elves can wield it. Magic that has been cast as an enchantment, will loss its effect because of magic decay.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The [Dead Sea scrolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea_Scrolls) are the better part of 2,000 years old.  Stone tablets, vellum, parchment, all can survive the centuries under the right conditions.  Are you asking how Kalven could "guarantee" it? or are you asking how well they'd survive the trip?  If the later, what are the conditions?  How are they initially stored?  What's the weather/environment like?  Are they important enough that people would copy them?

Comment: On top of what JBH raised, why are you using the magic tag? That would make any answer involving an abracadabra a good fit. They lasted because magic.

Comment: I have another question for potential clarification in line with what @JBH asked - is this about how the records Fredrietch collected have *already* survived 3000 years, or how would they survive *another* 3000 years? And are we talking about the compiled resources here or is it more like "how would The Chronicles of History survive another 3000 years" - the work written *based* on these resources?

Comment: The [Hattusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hattusa) archive is 3200 years old. The oldest Sumerian documents we still have are 5000 years old. What's the question?

Comment: @aCVn concerning your edit - isn't "*How **were** these [records] survive after 3000 years*" incorrect? It sounds better to me as "How **did** these [records] survive", although I admit I cannot justify that by citing grammar rules.

Comment: @vlaz You're right. Looks like I didn't look close enough.

Comment: @aCVn OK, I wanted to clear this up. It seems entirely possible that I was wrong myself. English rules can be weird sometimes (to put it mildly) :)

Comment: It turned out that the records weren't that vast after all. 3000 years ago was early Bronze Age. Given the lack of transport infrastructure and multilingual scribes, despite the time taken the total amount of information gathered was fairly modest. Add the fact that a lot of the information turned out to be repeated from various sources, the entire work ended up filling out a small shelf after compilation

Comment: Record keeping may prioritize usability or prioritize preservation. For usability, we would likely have papyrus scrolls on library-like shelves that, only if lucky, may survive 3,000 years of neglect and ruination. For preservation, ancients may build a sealed chamber where records will survive, but modern people must be lucky to find this chamber.

Comment: If your question can't be solved using your world's magic, then I'd recommend replacing the [tag:magic] tag with [tag:science-based] just to make that crystal clear.

Answer (score 5):

**Libraries**

For the Libraries it is pretty simple: Librarians preserved them by copying them on new scrolls/tomes/codices or they carved the most important information onto stone and where able to preserve them this way for millennia. (similar to how we still have access to Egyptian writings)

**Ruins**

This one is a bit harder depending on how long these ruins have been ruins it is very likely that scriptures have been lost. Here it could be that you have a scenario like [Pompeii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeii) where a volcano creates an air tight seal to preserve scriptures for millennia.

Or a solution which will probably not help for full 3000 years but these ruins could have crumbled in a way that would protect some writings from wind and weather which would persevere a part of the stored scrolls/codices/tomes for a few centuries or maybe even a bit more than a millennium.

**Cold**

What also could preserve your historical entries would be the cold maybe a ruin is located high up in the mountains or so far up north that it's close to permafrost or even within the permafrost region.

Answer (score 2):

Clay tablets as they were burned by Sumarians.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Heinrich. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions a user has while developing his/her fictional world. One-line answers are discouraged, as they fail to explain why the answer is the best fit. You may want to [edit] your post to add this detail, otherwise it may get deleted for being low-quality. If you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour] and check out our [site culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388/6986) to get a better understanding of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Look to the written records that have survived so long.

## Hieroglyphics

We have the writings of ancient Egyptians because they liked painting them on the inside of pyramids and then sealing them off from the world. Preventing the ravages of the years from erasing their words

## Ogham

An ancient Celtic written language, it tends to be carved in stone though possibly also on wood back in the day, it's mostly stone artifacts in sheltered locations that survive.

## Rosetta Stone

Another lump of carved rock with various languages written on it, but it does follow the theme.

## Conclusion

Your ancients didn't really believe in scrolls, though a few survive. They believed that anything that was important to pass on to their descendants should be literally carved into the walls of their temples and libraries. The palace has the history of the country carved into its walls, the temple has their religous texts carved into the walls. Every building has its purpose, every building has its carvings.

Answer (score 1):

Well maintained libraries would probably copy certain texts every so often to preserve them.

Papyrus if well preserved (kept in a dry and dark place) can last thousands of years. Check out the Kahun Gynaecological Papyrus as an example, it's 4,000 years old.

Engravings on certain stones are another good example of writing that has survived the riggers of time, the peace treaty between the Hittites and Egyptians is still fairly well preserved for being over 3,000 years old.

Wood and ink, would require really good conditions to survive that long, but bamboo books have been found in China that are 2,400 years old. Writing on waxed bark would also fit in this category.

Engravings, non-rusting metals/alloys can really withstand the test of time. Examples include silver scrolls from 2,700 year and the Iron pillar of Delhi which is 1,600 years old.

And don't forget that some cave paintings have survived for much greater time periods, so it is not unfeasible that paint on stones could last a fair amount of time too (in the right conditions).